# How to extract pitch bend from music generated by music21

Tags: python, music21

I want to extract some features from music made in music21 but I do not know how to do this.

You can see in the code below I know how to extract the following features; chord, note and pitch.

But i am unable to work out how to extract the following features; bend, velocity and duration.

How may i do this?

```
def get_notes():
""" Get all the notes and chords from the midi files in the ./midi_songs directory """
notes = []

for file in glob.glob("midi_songs/*.mid"):
    midi = converter.parse(file)

    print("Parsing %s" % file)

    notes_to_parse = None

    try: # file has instrument parts
        s2 = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)
        notes_to_parse = s2.parts[0].recurse() 
    except: # file has notes in a flat structure
        notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes

    for element in notes_to_parse:
        if isinstance(element, note.Note):
            notes.append(str(element.pitch))
        elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
            notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.normalOrder))

with open('data/notes', 'wb') as filepath:
    pickle.dump(notes, filepath)

return notes
```

Comment: Edited title and text to be clearer